# What am I doing wrong when using Vuex.Store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I want to take advantage of the "Vuex Store" capabilities to store and use the "isAuthenticated" variable throughout the project, in accordance with this, give access to routes. What is the my misstake? I spent a lot of time, reviewed a bunch of different ways to embed the vue store into the project, nothing came of it.

My "index.js" from "store":

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        isAuth: false,
    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthStatus(state, status) {
            state.isAuth = status;
        },
    },
});
export default store;
```

My "main.js" from "root(src)":

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    render: (h) => h(App),
    store,
    router,
    vuetify,
}).$mount('#app');
```

Browser error:
[image]

Comment: What are package versions?

Comment: where do you run the mutation? I mean which code is running and then that error popping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are massive, let's say, holes in your shown code (or you have not included them). First of all, `isAuth` is just a boolean (true/false). You have to use it somewhere in order for this to work (ie, in the `router.js` file to prevent navigation to certain routes depending on the condition).

Below is a simple implementation of user authentication and roles. I admit, it is a bit more complicated then your example, but I think you will get the idea.

### Router

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import store from "../store";

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/admin",
    name: "Admin",
    component: () => import("../views/Admin.vue"),
    children: [],
    meta: { role: "admin", requiresAuth: true },
  },
  {
    path: "/manager",
    name: "Manager",
    component: () => import("../views/Manager.vue"),
    children: [
      {
        path: "/employees",
        name: "Employees",
        component: () => import("../views/children/manager/Employees.vue"),
      },
    ],
    meta: { role: "manager", requiresAuth: true },
  },
  {
    path: "/employee",
    name: "Employee",
    component: () => import("../views/Employee.vue"),
    children: [],
    meta: { role: "employee", requiresAuth: true },
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: () => import("../views/Login.vue"),
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "About",
    component: () => import("../views/About.vue"),
    meta: { requiresAuth: false },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to) => {
  if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
    return { path: "login" };
  } else if (to.meta.role && to.meta.role !== store.getters.userRole) {
    return { path: store.getters.userRole };
  }
});

export default router;
```

Two items that are key here. The `meta` property on some of the routes and the `beforeEach` method that runs on every route change.

The meta property just tells the router, "Hi, these are my conditions, you must meet them before you can enter" (which we enforce in the `beforeEach` method with the checks).

### Store

```
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import { User } from "../types";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    user: <User>{},
  },
  getters: {
    isLoggedIn: (state): boolean => !!Object.keys(state.user).length,
    userRole: (state): string => state.user.role,
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USER(state, user): void {
      state.user = { ...user };
    },
  },
  actions: {},
  modules: {},
});
```

We are exporting this to the `router.js` file which is using the `getters` for the `beforeEach` method.

### App

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

The main file shouldn't have anything special inside of it.

### Versions

Vuex 4.0 is compatible with Vue3, so make sure you are using Vue3 (based on your syntax it doesn't look like it).

Comment: Understood. I don't have Vue3, so should I use Vuex 3.0.0 or below? Regarding the use of "store" in the router, I know. I just didn't add it here because I had a problem at the time of adding "store" to "main.js". Thank you!

Comment: Downgraded the vuex version and it worked! Thank you so much!